# Best references for a more intuitive introduction to Dynamical Systems, Ergodic Theory and Quantum Chaos

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

As a graduate math and physics student, I am introducing myself to the study of Smooth Dynamical Systems and Ergodic Theory, with the aim of applying it to Quantum Chaos and Quantum Ergodic Theory. I am starting with *Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems*, by Katok and Hasselblatt. Still, I feel like I need more "intuition" or motivation when presenting the main concepts of the theory. Also, I do not exactly know what are the most important sections in order to study Quantum Ergodic Theory (especially, Shnirelman theorem). Any help on this topic with appropriate references or suggestions about how I should focus my study? Thanks.